# Basic Java: dice rolling equation

Tags: java, dice

I've noticed the following equation in many dice rolling problems:

```
dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
```

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 5):

`Math.random()` returns a double between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive).

Multiply it by 6 and you'll get a double between 0.0 (inclusive) and 6 (exclusive).

Cast it to int and you'll get an integer between 0 and 5.

Add 1 and you get a random integer between 1 and 6.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.random` returns a random real number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).
`Math.random*6` will then give a real number between 0 (inclusive) and 6 (exclusive).
`(int)(Math.random*6)` will turn that to an int, in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
Sum +1 at the end to get something between 1 and 6 (dice roll).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an equation, it's an assignment.

[`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) produces a random number in the range [0,1). Multiply this by six, and you'll get a number in the range [0,6). That number is then truncated to an `int` and one is added, to get an integer in the range [1,7), which is the same as [1,6], as we're dealing with integers.
To make a long story short - this assignment produces a random number between 1 and 6 (inclusive), to simulate rolling a die.

Answer (score 1):

dice1 is an object with reference dice1.
Math.random() means the random method in the Math package.
*6 will return a number between 0 and 5.
+1 makes it between 1 and 6.
This is cast as an int, this means that it is turned into a number.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` produces a number in the range 0 to 0.9999..... Multiplying by 6 changes that range into 0.00 to 5.9999..... `int` then truncates that, producing either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. Adding 1 then produces the final 1..6,

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers to show why the formula gives a result in the right range, but none that address the distribution of those results. The distribution of a random number is just as important as its range.

Math.random() produces a number that is *uniformly distributed* in the range [0.0,1.0). (You will recall that the notation `[x,y)` where *x* ≤ *y* indicates that the range contains everything between *x* and *y*, including *x* but not including *y*.) *Uniformly distributed* means that if you take any subrange of that, such as [*a*,*b*) where 0.0 ≤ *a* ≤ *b* ≤ 1.0, the probability that the return value is in that range is *b-a*. That is, the probability depends only on the width of the subrange, not on where it starts.

Multiply by 6.0, and you have a number that is still uniformly distributed, but now in the range [0.0,6.0). Imagine that divided into the six subranges [0.0,1.0), [1.0,2.0), ... , [5.0,6.0). All of these subranges have the same width, so the probability that the number falls in any one of them is exactly the same as the probability that it falls in any other.

These subranges also have the property that when you cast a number in one of them to (int), you get the number at the bottom end of the range (as an int, of course). For example, casting anything in [3.0,4.0) to int gives you 3.

Since the number was equally likely to be in any range, after you cast to int you have an integer in 0 thru 5, with each of these six integers exactly as probable as any other. That is, you now have a uniform distribution of the integers 0 thru 5.

Add 1 to get a uniformly distributed integer in the range 1 thru 6.